# GTA V install updates help?

Tags: pc, grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

After installing from DVD, the game downloads a mandatory 5GB update and then a 350Mb patch.

- **Does the updater resume from a partial download?** I have a slow internet connection and will need to pause/resume it.
- **Can the update be downloaded as a separate file?** This would
  allow me to use FDM which helps resume failed downloads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes the updater resumes, I have had to restart my PC multiple times and it just deducts the filesize you have already downloaded.

And as far as my knowledge goes the update can only be downloaded through the client.

**EDIT:** The OP has proven me wrong! Apparently **you CAN download updates seperately** since a kind user uploaded the files to Mega. This can be found in [his answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/218499/109057)

Comment: @ardaozkal  could you please explain the procedure. thank you.

Comment: Hi @Rizky, could you please edit the 2nd part of the answer and point to the information on my answer. Thank You.

Comment: @rahulroy9202 All done, nice job on that find!

Answer (score 1):

### It is possible to download the update separately.

[instruction here.](http://gtaforums.com/topic/784070-5gb-patch-required-for-physical-copy-is-it-real/?p=1067312577)

> You can download the entire 5GB update the Rockstar Games Social Club
>   Launcher wants to install from mega.co.nz, some kind soul uploaded it
>   there (ukiuk found it linked on gtafive.pl):
>   https://mega.co.nz/#...f4wcGS_xCXpOYaw

- Close The RGSC/GTAV launcher if it's running.
- Download all 6 .partX.rar files from mega
- Open the first one with WinRAR/7-Zip or something like that
- Unpack the contents somewhere and then copy them to your

  `"C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V"`

  folder or unpack them there
  directly, OVERWRITING ANY EXISITING ONES, so in the end you have a
  directory structure like

  `"C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\update\x64\dlcpacks\mpheist\dlc.rpf"`
- Rename any ".part" files within the `"C:\Program Files\Rockstar Games\Grand Theft Auto V\update\x64\dlcpacks"` folder (that includes all subfolders of course!) to ".part.bak" or delete them.
- Start the RGSC launcher and download the 400MB update.

http://gtaforums.com/topic/784070-5gb-patch-required-for-physical-copy-is-it-real/?p=1067312470

**Download Links:**

- [part1.zip](http://forum.jvangent.nl/download/part1.zip)
- [part2.zip](http://forum.jvangent.nl/download/part2.zip)
- [part3.zip](http://forum.jvangent.nl/download/part3.zip)
- [part4.zip](http://forum.jvangent.nl/download/part4.zip)
- [part5.zip](http://forum.jvangent.nl/download/part5.zip)
- [part6.zip](http://forum.jvangent.nl/download/part6.zip)